# Convert a Column(str) to (Float) ,ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Null'

Tags: python, pandas

#### Im sorry folks, I know this question have been answered before,I tried all answers also research and tried different things for 4 hours. I could not get done.

I believe my data has something weird..

so following my data and my attempts:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({ "Cost" : [ "83.53462540716612" , "0.0" , "66.6315396408911" , "340.9281334351922" , "181.8128056341571" , "0.00" ]
```

My attempts:

```
###Attempt 0
# x["Cost"] = x["Cost"].str.replace(' ', '')
# x["Cost"] = x["Cost"].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)


###Attempt 1
#x = x.where((pd.notnull(x)), None)
#x["Cost"]  = float(len(x["Cost"]))


###Attempt 2
#x["Cost"].isdecimal()
#x = [float(x) for x in range(len(x["Cost"])) ]


###Attempt 3
#[float(x) for x in x["Cost"].strip().split()]


###Attempt 4
#x["Cost2"] = x["Cost"].append([float(str(x)) for x in x["Cost"].split(' ') if len(x)>1])


###Attempt 5
#x["Cost"]  = pd.get_dummies(x["Cost"]).values
```

Nothing works..
getting errors such:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Null'

# else, only a single dtype is given
# _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
# TODO(extension)
# Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
```

Comment: You didn't try `pd.to_numeric`? `pd.to_numeric(x.Cost)`

Comment: maybe in your data you have `Null` values, you should handle them before converting?

Comment: @yatu No, I will try it now!! thank you.  @Marcos so I try removing the Null values at  ```##Attempt 1 x.where((pd.notnull(x)), None) ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), and coerce errors so that they result in `NaN` values if they cannot be converted.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({ "Cost" : [ "Null", "1,083.53462540716612" , "0.0" , "66.6315396408911" , "340.9281334351922" , "181.8128056341571" , "0.00" ]})

x['Cost'] = pd.to_numeric(x['Cost'].str.replace(",", ""), errors='coerce')
>>> x

          Cost
0          NaN
1  1083.534625
2     0.000000
3    66.631540
4   340.928133
5   181.812806
6     0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, it worked!! just edit it ```x['Cost'] = pd.to_numeric(x['Cost'].str.replace(",", ""), errors='coerce') ```

Comment: Well just like peter, I spent so much time trying to achieve this. I really appreciated your answer !!!