# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Null' (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write the value of a row to "Null" but it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Null'`

test.csv:

```
SIDE,PRICE,QTY,OPEN
BUY,0.25,0.22,True
BUY,0.26,0.23,True
BUY,0.27,0.24,True
BUY,0.28,0.25,True
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

test_dataframe = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

test_dataframe.at[2, 'OPEN'] = False
test_dataframe.at[2, 'QTY'] = "Null"

test_dataframe.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

How can I write "Null" to a row because that's what I want?

Comment: Did you check the `test_dataframe.at[2, 'QTY'] = np.nan` ?

Comment: Yes, but I only want specific value that is "Null" not empty value.

Comment: Maybe this answer your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044391/convert-a-columnstr-to-float-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
test_dataframe.at[2, 'QTY'] = "Null"
```

You can use this instead to change the value of any row within any column to "Null"(i.e. In this case I have implemented it to the third row of the third column.

```
test_dataframe.loc[2, "QTY"] = 'Null'
```

This code worked well in  my case, please do comment if you are facing with any issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a string but a float:

```
df.at[2, 'QTY'] = float('nan')
```

Or, using numpy:

```
df.at[2, 'QTY'] = np.nan
```

While you could use "Null" (and recent versions of pandas will allow `df.at[2, 'QTY'] = "Null"`), this would convert your Series to object type and you would lose benefit of vectorization. Ask yourself the question "*what would be the benefit of having "Null"?*".

If your goal is just to modify a CSV, then use strings, not floats, when importing the data.

Comment: It may be useful to note that you can change the export of `np.nan` when saving as a csv, aka: `df.to_csv('file.csv', na_rep='Null')`

Comment: Yes, good point @BeRT2me, using real NaNs just makes more sense. Also for changing a single value I'm not sure loading pandas is really worth it, why not just modifying the CSV directly.

Comment: Honestly if it's a single value, why do it programmatically anyways, just edit the CSV in a text editor :')

Comment: Yes, exactly ;)